# Assign a download folder in IE8?

Tags: download, internet-explorer-8

is it possible to define the download directory in Internet Explorer 8? I can't find this basic browser option!

Answer (score 2):

*That's not a readily configurable option in Internet Explorer.*  But you can change it with a registry tweak.

Instructions:

> - Go to Start -> Run -> type regedit and enter
> - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ Software\ Microsoft\ Internet Explorer
> - Create a new String value with key Download Directory and set the value to a valid directory (ex: C:\Download) * if this key already exists, just modify the value

*Source:* http://www.techiecorner.com/81/how-to-specify-default-download-directory-in-internet-explorer/

Screenshots:

[image]

and

[image]

(Images from another tutorial, [here](http://www.windowsreference.com/internet-explorer/how-to-change-the-default-download-directory-for-internet-explorer/).)

Comment: @Olivier: if it worked for you, then considering accepting the answer; click the checkmark above.